# Get value of struct with interfaces

Tags: go, struct, request

I'm trying to parse this petition (https://www.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=MDABTC&limit=500)

I was having tons of problems to create an struct for it, so I used an automated tool, this is what my struct looks like:

```
type orderBook struct {
    Bids         [][]interface{} `json:"Bids"`
    Asks         [][]interface{} `json:"Asks"`
}
```

I recover and parse the petition by doing:

```
url := "https://www.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=MDABTC&limit=500"
resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}else{
    book := orderBook{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &book); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

But whenever I try to make an operation with the struct, like:

```
 v := book.Asks[i][0] * book.Asks[i][1]
```

I get an error:

> invalid operation: book.Asks[i][0] * book.Asks[i][1] (operator * not
>   defined on interface)

How do I define it? Do I need to create an struct for `bids/asks`, if so, how would that look like?

Sorry if this seems basic, I just started learning go.

Comment: You can't define it. You can only multiply numbers. Here you're trying to multiply two `interface{}`s. If you know they'll be, say, `float`s, you should define that as the type rather than `interface{}`. If you don't, then you can't multiply them until you prove (by type assertion) that they're numbers.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Adrian They needed to be strings, I did it, but when I try to cast them with float64() I get this error  cannot convert book.Asks[i][0] (type string) to type float64, what am I missing?

Comment: Because underlying values of interface is float64 which is by default in case of unmarshal json having integer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Golang [Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

> For an expression x of interface type and a type T, the primary
>   expression

```
x.(T)
```

> asserts that x is not nil and that the value stored in x is of type T.
>   The notation x.(T) is called a type assertion.

Fetching an underlying value of string type you need to type assert to string from interface.

```
books.Asks[0][0].(string)
```

For performing an arithmetic operation on same you needs to convert string into float64 to take into account decimal values

```
v := strconv.ParseFloat(books.Asks[0][0].(string), 64) * strconv.ParseFloat(books.Asks[0][1].(string), 64)
```

Checkout code on [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NX-R2C7m4WL)

Comment: That was it, in the playground is specified, but id you don't get also the second parameter, strconv.ParseFloat fails (asks1, err := strconv.ParseFloat(books.Asks[0][0].(string), 64))

Comment: I used constants for simplification rather than looping to get id value If you wants to loop to id you can loop through the slice of data.

Comment: I have edited the code looping over slice of interface to get data on basis of id. Please check out on Go Playground

Answer (score 1):

Note that you could define proper structs that unmarshal from the JSON document by implementing the [`json.Unmarshaler` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler).

For example ([on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/97DBxZ4CdyE)):

```
type OrderBook struct {
  Asks, Bids   []Order
  LastUpdateId int
}

type Order struct {
  Price, Volume float64
}

func (o *Order) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
  values := make([]interface{}, 0, 3)
  err := json.Unmarshal(bs, &values)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  // TODO: more error checking re: len(values), and their types.
  price, err := strconv.ParseFloat(values[0].(string), 10)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  volume, err := strconv.ParseFloat(values[1].(string), 10)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  *o = Order{price, volume}
  return nil
}
```

As such, unmarshaling those documents looks idiomatic:

```
func main() {
  book := OrderBook{}
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonstr), &book)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("Asks:   %#v\n", book.Asks)
  fmt.Printf("Bids:   %#v\n", book.Bids)
  fmt.Printf("Update: %#v\n", book.LastUpdateId)
  // Asks:   []main.Order{main.Order{Price:0.00013186, Volume:167}, main.Order{Price:0.00013187, Volume:128}, ...
  // Bids:   []main.Order{main.Order{Price:0.00013181, Volume:110}, main.Order{Price:0.00013127, Volume:502}, ...
  // Update: 14069188
}
```