# How do I extract nested JSON data?

Tags: go

I have the following in data.json:

```
{  
    "table":"orderBook10",
    "action":"update",
    "data":[  
       {  
          "symbol":"XBTUSD",
          "bids":[  
             [  
                3996,
                49137
             ],
             [  
                3995.5,
                116
             ],
             [  
                3995,
                165
             ],
             [  
                3994.5,
                166
             ],
             [  
                3994,
                237
             ],
             [  
                3993.5,
                45
             ],
             [  
                3992,
                20064
             ],
             [  
                3991.5,
                209
             ],
             [  
                3991,
                134
             ],
             [  
                3990.5,
                2948
             ]
          ],
          "timestamp":"2019-03-23T00:34:40.505Z",
          "asks":[  
             [  
                3996.5,
                975
             ],
             [  
                3997,
                289
             ],
             [  
                3997.5,
                334
             ],
             [  
                3998,
                419
             ],
             [  
                3998.5,
                423
             ],
             [  
                3999,
                930
             ],
             [  
                3999.5,
                547
             ],
             [  
                4000,
                538
             ],
             [  
                4000.5,
                703
             ],
             [  
                4001,
                997
             ]
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
```

My program can so far extract the `data` field:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {

    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./data.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var ob map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(dat, &ob); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ob["data"])
}
```

I would now like to extract the nested "asks" field.

I've tried:

```
data := ob["data"]
asks := data["asks"].([][]int)
```

but this results in a syntax error that I can't decipher.

How do I assign the nested `asks` field to a variable?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952864/5728991) to a related question.

Comment: use `ob["data"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["asks"]`

Answer (score 1):

Your `ob["data"]` `JSON` structure is as follows:

```
([]interface {}) {
  (map[string]interface {}) {
    (string) "": (string) "",
    (string) "": ([]interface {}) {
      ([]interface {}) {
        (float64),
        (float64) 
      }
    },
    (string) "": (string) "",
    (string) "": ([]interface {}) {
      ([]interface {}) {
        (float64),
        (float64)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so you would need to use the following:

```
ob["data"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["asks"]
```

which:

- casts `ob["data"]` to `[]interface{}`
- use the first (and in your example, the only) element `[0]`
- cast this element to `map[string]interface{}`, and
- then extract `"asks"`

---

Note:
Unless you are sure, always use this form `t, ok := i.(T)` for [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15):

> If i holds a T, then t will be the underlying value and ok will be true.
>
> If not, ok will be false and t will be the zero value of type T, and no panic occurs.

Answer (score 1):

The approach to parse any JSON can be achieved by the following.

**Step 1:** Define the Structures

```
type OuterJson struct {
  Table string `json:"table"`
  Action string `json:"action"`
  DataJson []DataJson `json:"data"`
}

type DataJson struct {
  Symbol string `json:"symbol"`
  Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
  BidsJson [][]float64 `json:"bids"`
  AsksJson [][]float64 `json:"asks"`

}
```

**Step 2:** Declare the input and output

```
input := `{"table":"orderBook10","action":"update","data":[{"symbol":"XBTUSD","bids":[[3996,49137],[3995.5,116],[3995,165],[3994.5,166],[3994,237],[3993.5,45],[3992,20064],[3991.5,209],[3991,134],[3990.5,2948]],"timestamp":"2019-03-23T00:34:40.505Z","asks":[[3996.5,975],[3997,289],[3997.5,334],[3998,419],[3998.5,423],[3999,930],[3999.5,547],[4000,538],[4000.5,703],[4001,997]]}]}`
var output OuterJson
```

**Step 3:** Obtain the output from the given input (or Unmarshalling)

```
json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &output)
```

Combining all, you get

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type OuterJson struct {
  Table string `json:"table"`
  Action string `json:"action"`
  DataJson []DataJson `json:"data"`
}

type DataJson struct {
  Symbol string `json:"symbol"`
  Timestamp string `json:"timestamp"`
  BidsJson [][]float64 `json:"bids"`
  AsksJson [][]float64 `json:"asks"`

}  

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    input := `{"table":"orderBook10","action":"update","data":[{"symbol":"XBTUSD","bids":[[3996,49137],[3995.5,116],[3995,165],[3994.5,166],[3994,237],[3993.5,45],[3992,20064],[3991.5,209],[3991,134],[3990.5,2948]],"timestamp":"2019-03-23T00:34:40.505Z","asks":[[3996.5,975],[3997,289],[3997.5,334],[3998,419],[3998.5,423],[3999,930],[3999.5,547],[4000,538],[4000.5,703],[4001,997]]}]}`
    var output OuterJson
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &output)
    fmt.Println(output)     
}
```

Try this [link](https://play.golang.org/p/QEcoV0TxJW-)

Answer (score 0):

You Struct structure should be

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)
type JsonData struct {
    Table  string `json:"table"`
    Action string `json:"action"`
    Data   []struct {
        Symbol    string      `json:"symbol"`
        Bids      [][]int     `json:"bids"`
        Timestamp time.Time   `json:"timestamp"`
        Asks      [][]float64 `json:"asks"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./data.json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var ob JsonData
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dat), &ob); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ob)
   }
```

You can make use of below links for generating struct from nested JSON objects.

https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

http://json2struct.mervine.net/